# If each number line also has the Imaginary number line in it, does that mean x, y, z is six dimensions?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra

Are we to assume that x is two dimensional?
I can somewhat picture this, but I'm having trouble with a number line for i (square root of negative one) with more than one dimension.

i is not a replacement for y is it? Or can Linear Algebra and Calculus be done with the Imaginary Number line standing in for y?

A [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T647CGsuOVU) on Imaginary Numbers by Welch Labs on YouTube.

Comment: When you say “number line”, do you mean coordinate axis (that is, $x$ axis, $y$ axis and $z$ axis)?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I don't know which precise math terms to use. I'll have to remember 'coordinate axis'.

Answer (score 0):

You should study Vector Spaces.  This will formalize the concept of dimension.  However, an important point is that a vector has an associated field.  We usually say something like V is a vector space over F.  Often the field is obvious and unstated but this is a case where you need to be fussy.

Triples of complex numbers could be regarded as a vector space over the field of complex numbers in which case the dimension would be $3$ not $6$.

The same set could also be regarded as a vector space over the field of real numbers in which case the dimension would be $6$.

It could even be regarded as a vector space over the field of rational numbers in which case the dimension would be infinite.

Any field is a vector space over itself and the dimension will always be $1$.  The complex numbers are not inherently $2$ dimensional.  They are $1$ dimensional over themselves. It is just intuition from day to day life and early mathematics which biases us towards the real viewpoint.